# Bitmap from image to path back to image... no reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, bitmap, c++-cli, imagemagick

Basically, I'm using magick++ in visual studio 2010. Magick++ can only read images from filepaths.

So, in this object there are two images, The first one is saved to a path.

Magick reads this path, analyzes the image, and then the analyzed image is currently a path i.e. "C:\USERS\theImg.png", what i want to do is take `theImg.png` and set it to the second bitmap (already using:
 `System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bmp = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap("dud2.png")` and then `objectInQuestion->imgs->analyzed img = bmp`), but when this runs through a loop since this has to be done mutliple times, `dud2.png` is never overwritten.

Comment: You'll probably want to add the managed-c++ tag.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Never mind, I see you have C++-cli.